# Perl regular expression to get 'This text':(

Tags: regex, perl

for example , if i have `'Sample text':(`

My $1 should be `Sample text`, so any string which is enclosed in `' '` and is before `:(`

Comment: Sounds [`'([^']*)':\(`](https://regex101.com/r/HMqjZd/1/) would do

Comment: i tried it on this website https://regex101.com/ , for some reason it's not working.

Comment: 1. Perl regexes is not one of the option supported regex101. /// 2. However PCRE is close enough in this case, and the pattern most assuredly does work for both PCRE and Perl. You didn't show what you did, so we don't know what you did wrong.

Comment: May there be another characters between the closing `'` and the `:`? Is there always a `:(`? Is there always only one text in a line? Please give some more examples...

Comment: Why the down votes? It is expected that you show that you have tried to solve the problem. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/2173773) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not adding anything new here but just some samples and a place for you to test it yourself and see perhaps how it works. There are two assumptions here:

1. No escape characters, such as `'Sam\'ple text'`.
2. `:(` is directly after your string. If it's not, you'd want to do a lookahead instead.
3. `+` requires at least one character in your string. So `'a':(` would be valid but `'':(` would not. If you want to allow empty strings, use `*` instead of `+`.

[`'([^']+)':\(`](https://regex101.com/r/LGP0Iz/1)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following will do the trick:

```perl
/'([^']*)':\(/
```

For example,

```perl
my $str = "'Sample text':(";
my ($match) = $str =~ /'([^']*)':\(/
   or die("No match\n");

say $match;   # Sample text
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simplest code to answer the question:

```perl
#/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

"'Sample text':(" =~ /'(.*)':\(/;
print "$1\n"
```

Comment: What new information are you trying provide that was not already given in other answers?

Comment: @joanis what information do you interpret as new/old?

Comment: This answer provides no additional information, given the answers that have already been here for many days. But maybe it does: if you're trying to propose a different perspective, explain it and I will remove my downvote.

Comment: because it provides as simple solution as possible to the requester